# How to include curl.h in CLion?

Tags: c++, curl, raspberry-pi, clion

I am programming a Raspberry Pi as a Remote Linux Host in my PC with CLion. In order to include `curl` I executed:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then included in my C++ file:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

And in CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(Central)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Central main.cpp services/MyService.cpp services/MyService.h model/MyModel.cpp model/MyModel.h)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "bin")

find_package (CURL)
if (CURL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(Central ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
else()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "LibCurl is not found in your system.")
endif (CURL_FOUND)

target_link_libraries(Central ${LIBS})
```

Honestly, I am COMPLETELY new to CMake and this code I copied from a blog post, I have no idea on how much I need it or if anything is missing there.

Then I copied and pasted an example from the `curl` website.

The code executes fine but all the `curl` definitions are marked as erros in CLion:

[image: CUrl error]

So I can't get autocomplete from `curl`.

The `#include <curl/curl.h>` gives me this error:

[image: curl not found]

But again, the code executes fine, and other libraries inside the Raspberry Pi don't give me this error.

I can find the library at `usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/curl/curl.h` inside the Raspberry Pi, but including this path gives me the same error.

Someone could explain me what's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the entire contents of your CMakeLists.txt file what's shown?

Comment: No, I will update it

Comment: @AlecC now it's all there

Comment: Try `set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl")` before `find_package (CURL)`.

Comment: It didn't work, even restarted CLion to be sure.

Comment: What message do you get from the CMake tab along the bottom after reloading the project? And what error messages does the compiler give when building?

Comment: You could also try adding `include_directories(x)` where x is the path to the folder that contains curl.h. (e.g., `include_directories(/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/) )

Comment: There are no error messages, the code execute fine, I only get the error from CLion

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by doing `Tools | Resync with Remote Hosts`.